# Extract a portion of an image in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image, playing-cards

I have a PNG of a deck of cards as 1 image (it has all 52 cards combined into 1 image file).  How do I extract an individual card out as I need it (or extract them all into separate image files at start up).

I understand the logic of know which row and column to get, its the actual image manipulation code I am having trouble with.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and using VB (although sample code in any .NET language would do).

I am not allowed to post the image itself, but here is an example image

http://www.jfitz.com/cards/windows-playing-cards.png

Thanks.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Answer (score 9):

This will load the original and create a cropped version starting at (0,0) and with dimensions of 100x100. You'd have to write the logic to iterate over each card, know when to move to the next row, etc. However, this should help you with pulling out the cards once you know the coordinates and dimensions.

```
Bitmap cards = new Bitmap(@"C:\SomePath\");
Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
Bitmap card = (Bitmap)cards.Clone(srcRect, cards.PixelFormat);
```

BTW, I didn't include the call to card.Save() because there are a lot of options to set during a save and it's a bit outside of the scope of your question. However, for information on how to save it to disk, [see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80.aspx).

Comment: In case anyone is interested, here is the equivalent VB.NET code

        Dim cards As Bitmap = New Bitmap("C:\tpm\card_4color.png")
        Dim srcRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)
        Dim card As Bitmap = cards.Clone(srcRect, cards.PixelFormat)


Thanks Scott, code worked perfectly.

Comment: Can someone provide the WinRT version?

Answer (score 0):

I was extremely bored, see if this helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CardDeck
{
    public class CardCropper
    {
        private Bitmap _source;
        private int _cardsPerRow;
        private int _rowCount;
        private int _cardCount;
        private int _cardWidth;
        private int _cardHeight;

        public CardCropper(Bitmap source, int rowCount, int cardsPerRow)
        {
            _source = source;
            _cardsPerRow = cardsPerRow;
            _rowCount = rowCount;
            _cardCount = _cardsPerRow * _rowCount;
            _cardWidth = source.Width / _cardsPerRow;
            _cardHeight = source.Height / _rowCount;
        }

        public Bitmap[,] CropCards()
        {
            var cards = new Bitmap[_rowCount, _cardsPerRow];

            for (int y = 0; y < _rowCount; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < _cardsPerRow; x++)
                {
                    cards[y, x] = CropCard(x, y);
                }
            }

            return cards;
        }

        private Bitmap CropCard(int x, int y)
        {
            var rect = new Rectangle(x * _cardWidth, y * _cardHeight, _cardWidth, _cardHeight);

            return _source.Clone(rect, _source.PixelFormat);
        }
    }

    public class CardDeck
    {
        private int _limit;
        private int _cardsPerRow;
        private int _index = 0;
        private Bitmap[,] _cards;

        public int Index
        {
            get
            {
                CheckLimits();
                return _index;
            }
            set
            {
                _index = value;
                CheckLimits();
            }
        }

        public CardDeck(Bitmap[,] cards, int rowCount, int cardsPerRow)
        {
            _cards = cards;
            _limit = rowCount * cardsPerRow;
            _cardsPerRow = cardsPerRow;            
        }


        public Image GetCardFromIndex()
        {
            var point = GetPointFromIndex();

            return _cards[point.Y, point.X];
        }

        private void CheckLimits()
        {
            if (_index >= _limit)
            {
                _index = 0;
            }

            if (_index < 0)
            {
                _index = _limit - 1;
            }
        }

        private Point GetPointFromIndex()
        {
            int x = this.Index % _cardsPerRow;
            int y = this.Index / _cardsPerRow;

            return new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CardDeck
{
    public partial class CardDeckForm : Form
    {
        private CardDeck _cardDeck = null;

        public CardDeckForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadCards();

            ShowImage();
        }

        private void LoadCards()
        {
            using (var source = new Bitmap(@"AllCards.png"))
            {
                var cards = new CardCropper(source, rowCount: 4, cardsPerRow: 13).CropCards();
                _cardDeck = new CardDeck(cards, rowCount: 4, cardsPerRow : 13);
            }
        }

        private void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _cardDeck.Index++;
            ShowImage();
        }

        private void PreviousButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _cardDeck.Index--;
            ShowImage();
        }

        private void ShowImage()
        {
            this.cardPictureBox.Image = _cardDeck.GetCardFromIndex();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant they're up to OP to measure.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static System.Drawing.Image CropBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int cropX, int cropY, int cropWidth, int cropHeight)
        {
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
            System.Drawing.Image cropped = bitmap.Clone(rect, bitmap.PixelFormat);
            return cropped;
        }
```